# Fulltext index query - illogical

Tags: sql, full-text-search

I have a fulltext index on my table but am getting weird results...

Think a table of current Toys... (huggle buddy is "hot" apparently at the moment)

If a I search for Huggle on my table the results brought up are "Huggle Buddy" toys and I get 12 results...thats fine, perfect.

But if I search for "Huggle Buddy" I get almost 500 results, which is ok as i know its searching both words and combinations, but, the items with Huggle Buddy in the title do not appear first, how do i fix that? e.g. Is there an order by scoring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the search term in quotes so it will only search for an exact match. You'll only get results that contain the exact match "Huggle Buddy".

Comment: @ K'Shin Thats not the question - the question is how do i move most relevant results to the top

Comment: You can do 2 searches: first one for the exact match and then append the second one for huggle or buddy, combine them with an exclude clause so you don't get the results twice.